# Connect windows machine to Linux VPS

Tags: windows, networking, debian, ftp, network-shares

I have setup a VPS running debian to host some websites and other applications.

For one of the projects that I am working on I need to allow users on windows PC's to connect to a folder on the VPS to view its files.

I would like to achieve this in a similar way to mapping a network drive on windows, because they don't have any technical knowledge of ftp or similar.

Is there any way to allow people to either connect to the server to access files, or what would probably be best, automatically send the files to a windows machine to host them on the local network?

Comment: You think you want it like that but really you don’t. Windows File Sharing is not suitable for WAN use. WebDAV also sucks. Just use FTP. It’s easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seem [win-sshfs](https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs) will fit your needs.

You will be able to set a drive letter and point to a remote folder on you VPS.

[image: Screenshot of win-sshfs]